# How can i check if the field exist in elasticsearch 1.3

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to check if the field exist in elasticsearch 1.3, the field is `job_portal_id`, please find my query as below

also i'm using Elasticsearch's php [package](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) for that

```
array:2 [
   "query" => array:1 [
"filtered" => array:2 [
  "query" => []
  "filter" => array:2 [
    "constant_score" => array:1 [
      "exists" => array:1 [
        "field" => "job_portal_id"
      ]
    ]
    "term" => array:1 [
      "location.country_code" => "ae"
    ]
  ]
  ....
```

When I run this query i get error exception in query

```
SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures
```

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: @CodeNotFound added the error message